# A misunderstanding of a Halmos Naive set theory book passage.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding the following passage from Halmos Naive set theory book:
[image].What I cannot understand is his way of thinking.He first defines two sets to be equal if and only if they have the same elements and after that he proposes an example (the ancestor example) that proves the existence of cases where two sets having the same elements are not equal which is a contradiction. What is my misconception? (Excuse me if it is a problem related with bad english language knowledge but again I would like to know how my misunderstanding is solved). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: He's basically saying that the axiom of extension is something we need as axiom, because we can come up with ideas with a notion of belonging (i.e. ancestors) that don't follow axiom of extension

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information that is not otherwise present in your post. See [here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The example shows that humans, with the membership "being ancestor of" are not sets of ancestors. In particular, when you said `that proves the existence of cases where two sets having the same elements are not equal`, no, they wouldn't be sets.